# Webサービスを作った後、Googleやヤフーに登録(検索されるようにする)にはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

RailsでWebサービスを作りました。
2日前にベーシック認証を外したのですが、Googleやヤフーでサービス名を検索したところ、まだサイトが表示されません。
以下のサイトでも調べましたが表示されませんでした。
http://checker.search-rank-check.com/#result

Googleやヤフーに登録(検索されるようにする)にはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
ご教示の程、宜しくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Google へのサイトの登録**
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34397?hl=ja&ref_topic=3309469

> Google の検索結果に、ご自身のサイトを無料で簡単に表示させることができます。Google にサイトを送信する必要すらありません。Google は完全に自動化された検索エンジンです。「ウェブクローラ」というソフトウェアを使用して定期的にウェブを探索し、見つかったサイトを Google のインデックスに登録しています。Google 検索結果に表示されるサイトのほとんどは、手動で登録されたものではなく、ロボットがウェブをクロールして見つかったサイトが自動的に追加されたものです。

特に作業は必要ありませんが、見つけてもらうのを待てない場合は下記の手順を実施してください。

**Webマスターチェックリスト** (PDF)
https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/DED5FEC4F7C3118641D255CD0843F9ECC50F

> 「site:」の後に自分のドメインを指定して検索し、ページがインデックスに登録されているか確認しましょう（例:site:example.com）。 自分のサイトが表示されない場合は、Google Search Console（g.co/searchconsole）でウェブサイトの所有権を確認して、サイトが インデックスに登録されるよう google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url でサイトの情報を送信しましょう。

なお、**Yahoo! JAPANの検索はGoogleの検索エンジンを使っている**ので、検索結果のカスタマイズはあるものの基本的に同じものです。サイトを見つけてもらうために、Yahoo! JAPAN向けの作業をする必要はありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！インデックスに登録されているのが確認できました。

Answer (score 0):

これはSEOというやつですね。
あまりやるとランクを下げられるところもありますが、基本的にはリンクされていないとクローラーが拾えないので、多くのサイトにリンクされるようにすることでしょうか。